# Phantom Js with Node and Angular - ng-repeat not rendering

Tags: angularjs, node.js, phantomjs

I have an angular App, using angular-ui-router.
Page I have built looks fine.
I am trying to take a snapshot of the html and create a pdf.
To do this, I am using Phantom.

I can trigger and create a PDF fine, but it doesn't render my ng-repeat section of the HTML.

My HTML:

```
<div>{{vm.hello}}</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">Heading</div>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="record in vm.records">
    <div class="col-xs-2">Space</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" ng-bind="record.id"></div>
</div>
```

My controller triggers on load to populate vm.records. 
vm.hello is hardcoded and renders fine.
Nothing in my ng-repeat loads.

My Node js code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
function pdf(req, res) {
  console.log('pdf function entered');
  var url = "http://myapp.com/page";
  phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
      page.viewportSize = {
        width: 1400,
        height: 1024
      };

      page.property('onLoadFinished', function(status) {
        console.log("Load Finished with status " + status);
      });

      page.open(url).then(function(status) {
          page.render('test.pdf', {
            format: 'pdf',
            quality: '100'
          }).then(function() {
            console.log("File Created");
            page.close();
            ph.exit();
          });
        });
    });
  });
  res.status(200).send();
}
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why the ng-repeat won't work?  I've tried adding delays in and such based on other questions/answers, but just can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events (old [Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-3_phantomnodeerrors-js), so it might not work in exactly the same way). Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have to call

```
window.callPhantom();
```

when the render is completed

Next is you have to call it inside $timeout like this

```
$timeout(function(){
            window.callPhantom();
            return;
})
```

to avoid call it before binding